# How to respond to Instant Payment notification with header status 200

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an API with the following requiements;
**`Your application must respond to each IPN message with HTTP header status code 200, whether or not you intend to do anything with it.`**

This is the API processing code i have tried;

```
def success
    transaction =Transaction.find_by_merchant_reference(params[:external_ref])

    if transaction && transaction.status != "Completed"
        date_time = params[:date_time]
        amount = params[:amount]
        narrative = params[:narrative]
        network_ref = params[:network_ref]
        external_ref = params[:external_ref]
        msisdn = params[:msisdn]
        signature = params[:signature]

        if verfiy_signiture(date_time,amount,narrative,network_ref,external_ref,msisdn) == signature
            user = User.find(transaction.user_id)
            user.balance = (user.balance+transaction.amount*0.975)
            user.save() 
            transaction.status ="Completed"         
            TopUp.account_topup(user.name, user.email, user.currency, transaction.amount, transaction.merchant_reference).deliver
            flash[:notice] = "##################################3"
            user_home_path(@current_user)
        end

    end

    render :status => 200

end
```

However this show errors regarding to missing template yet this is an instant payment notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
render nothing: true, status: 200
```

This tells rails not to render a template